# Convex hull of multiple circles

Tags: geometry

I am having difficulties figuring the convex hull of multiple circles. If I have 2 circles that are disjoint what is their convex hull and how to find it? Thank you

Comment: where do your circles live? $\Bbb R^2$? $\Bbb R^3$? $\Bbb R^4$?

Comment: sorry because i ommited this; it's R2

Comment: In general, I think to find convex hull of a set $A$ one just take the union of all segments with two end-points in $A$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The convex hull of a set of circles is a curvilinear polygon made of portions of the circumferences joined with common tangents.

When all radii are equal, you can "deflate" the circles to radius $0$, compute the convex hull of the points (the centers), and inflate back.

When the radii are different, take a look at "A convex hull algorithm for discs, and applications, D. Rappaport".

[image]

If you just have two disjoint circles, find the common tangency points.

Comment: direct tangents

Comment: Will it be possible for you to elaborate more on circle with different radii?

Comment: @pushpen.paul: I referred to a paper. It describes a Divide & Conquer approach, where you recursivey form the hulls of two subsest of equal size, the merge the hulls by a simultaneous traversal.